# SQL Server 2008 R2 using PIVOT with varchar columns not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2, I have this simple table

[image]

What I was trying to do is make a selection from this table and get this following result

```
x |      1     |       2     |      3
--+------------+-------------+------------
1 |   first 1  |    first 2  |    first 3
2 |   Second 1 |    second 2 |    second 3
```

I thought that can be done with  `PIVOT`

I don't know much about `PIVOT` AND all my search result found using PIVOT with `Count()` . `SUM()`, `AVG()` which will not work in my table since I'm trying to `PIVOT` on a `varchar` column

*Question* am I using the right function? Or is there something else I need to know to solve this issue? Any help will be appreciated

**I tried this** with no luck

```
PIVOT(count(x) FOR value IN ([1],[2],[3]) )as total 
PIVOT(count(y) FOR value IN ([1],[2],[3]) )as total  // This one is the nearest 
of what i wand  but instead of the column value values i get 0
```

Here is the query if any one to test it

```
CREATE TABLE #test (x int , y int , value Varchar(50))
INSERT INTO #test VALUES(1,51,'first 1')
INSERT INTO #test VALUES(1,52,'first 2')
INSERT INTO #test VALUES(1,53,'first 3')
INSERT INTO #test VALUES(2,51,'Second 1')
INSERT INTO #test VALUES(2,52,'Second 2')
INSERT INTO #test VALUES(2,53,'Second 3')
SELECT * FROM #test
  PIVOT(count(y) FOR value IN ([1],[2],[3]) )as total 
 DROP TABLE #test
```

Comment: are you trying to return this - [SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/634c8/8)

Comment: I smell a new question who's answer involves dynamic sql.

Comment: @MinaGabriel See my edit, it includes both dynamic sql and if the values are known.

Comment: I had a couple queries like this and nobody could figure out why I made them dynamic sql... until they solved the problem themselves.  One of those, "I'll rewrite this and it will be 100 times better" and when you're done, it's the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you are using the PIVOT function the values inside the IN clause need to match a value that you are selecting.  Your current data does not include 1, 2, or 3.  You can use `row_number()` to assign a value for each `x`:

```
select x, [1], [2], [3]
from
(
  select x, value,
    row_number() over(partition by x order by y) rn
  from test
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for rn in ([1], [2], [3])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/634c8/13).  If you then have a unknown number of values for each `x`, then you will want to use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(row_number() over(partition by x order by y)) 
                    from test
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT x,' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              select x, value,
                row_number() over(partition by x order by y) rn
              from test
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for rn in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/634c8/16)

Answer (score 2):

Key is to use the Max function for text fields.

Query:

```
SELECT X, [51] [1], [52] [2], [53] [3]
FROM (select * from test) t
  PIVOT(max(Value) FOR Y IN ([51], [52], [53]) )as total
```

[Working demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/59e55/16)

Answer (score 1):

You say `value IN ([1],[2],[3])`. This means "match if value is exactly equal to 1, 2 or 3". But in your table it never is. Something is not right there.

Comment: comment and not an answer?

Comment: Answer because it tells him how to solve his problem. Did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM #test
 PIVOT(MAX(value) FOR y IN ([51],[52],[53]) )as total
```

Answer (score 1):

I give you a trick but it hasn't meaning.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT x, y-50 as y, value FROM test) src
  PIVOT(max(value) FOR y IN ([1],[2],[3]) )as total
```