# SQL Pivot returns null values when pivoting (n)varchar data

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I'm struggling to pivot data in Microsoft SQL Server 2012. When I try to perform a pivot with varchar values, the script returns *NULL* values for all records. My code looks like this:

```
select [Identifier], [Geography Description], [Temperature Description], [Humidity Description], [Pressure Description]
from 
    (
        select [Identifier], [AttributeID], [AttributeValue]
            from [dbo].[StringAttributeValues]
    ) as A

PIVOT

(
    max(AttributeID)
    for [AttributeValue] in ([Geography Description], [Temperature Description], [Humidity Description], [Pressure Description])
) as B
```

I then followed the advice of the top most answer of this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753496/sql-server-2008-r2-using-pivot-with-varchar-columns-not-working) and modified my script. The end result was that my script still returns *NULL* values for every record across all columns.

```
select [Identifier], [1] as [Geography Description], [2] as [Temperature Description], [3] as [Humidity Description], [4] as [Pressure Description]
from 
    (
        select [Identifier], [AttributeID], [AttributeValue]
            from [dbo].[StringAttributeValues]
    ) as A

PIVOT

(
    max(AttributeID)
    for [AttributeValue] in ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) as B
```

Here is some code detailing my table structure and some sample values to work with:

```
    create table [dbo].[StringAttributeValues]
(
    [Identifier] int
    ,[AttributeID] int
    ,[AttributeValue] nvarchar(15)
)

insert into dbo.StringAttributeValues ([Identifier], [AttributeID], [AttributeValue]) values (1, 1, 'Mountains')
insert into dbo.StringAttributeValues ([Identifier], [AttributeID], [AttributeValue]) values (2, 1, 'Coast')
insert into dbo.StringAttributeValues ([Identifier], [AttributeID], [AttributeValue]) values (3, 1, 'Desert')
insert into dbo.StringAttributeValues ([Identifier], [AttributeID], [AttributeValue]) values (4, 1, 'Jungle')
insert into dbo.StringAttributeValues ([Identifier], [AttributeID], [AttributeValue]) values (5, 1, 'Plains')
insert into dbo.StringAttributeValues ([Identifier], [AttributeID], [AttributeValue]) values (1, 2, 'Cold')
insert into dbo.StringAttributeValues ([Identifier], [AttributeID], [AttributeValue]) values (2, 2, 'Warm')
insert into dbo.StringAttributeValues ([Identifier], [AttributeID], [AttributeValue]) values (3, 2, 'Hot')
insert into dbo.StringAttributeValues ([Identifier], [AttributeID], [AttributeValue]) values (4, 2, 'Hot')
insert into dbo.StringAttributeValues ([Identifier], [AttributeID], [AttributeValue]) values (5, 2, 'Hot')
insert into dbo.StringAttributeValues ([Identifier], [AttributeID], [AttributeValue]) values (1, 3, 'Dry')
insert into dbo.StringAttributeValues ([Identifier], [AttributeID], [AttributeValue]) values (2, 3, 'Humid')
insert into dbo.StringAttributeValues ([Identifier], [AttributeID], [AttributeValue]) values (3, 3, 'Dry')
insert into dbo.StringAttributeValues ([Identifier], [AttributeID], [AttributeValue]) values (4, 3, 'Humid')
insert into dbo.StringAttributeValues ([Identifier], [AttributeID], [AttributeValue]) values (5, 3, 'Dry')
insert into dbo.StringAttributeValues ([Identifier], [AttributeID], [AttributeValue]) values (1, 4, 'High')
insert into dbo.StringAttributeValues ([Identifier], [AttributeID], [AttributeValue]) values (2, 4, 'Low')
insert into dbo.StringAttributeValues ([Identifier], [AttributeID], [AttributeValue]) values (3, 4, 'High')
insert into dbo.StringAttributeValues ([Identifier], [AttributeID], [AttributeValue]) values (4, 4, 'Low')
insert into dbo.StringAttributeValues ([Identifier], [AttributeID], [AttributeValue]) values (5, 4, 'Low')
```

Can anyone please provide me with some insight as to why this is happening and how I fix it?

(It's a pretty simple procedure to right in languages like MATLAB, C#, Python, etc)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
select [Identifier], [1] as [Geography Description], [2] as [Temperature Description], [3] as [Humidity Description], [4] as [Pressure Description]
from 
    (
        select [Identifier], [AttributeID], [AttributeValue]

            from [dbo].[StringAttributeValues]
    ) as x

PIVOT

(
    max([AttributeValue])
    for [AttributeID] in ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) as piv
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/231aa/5)

Comment: Not my DV but the `row_number()` isn't doing anything here.  The issue with their query is they had a syntax issue with their query which was causing the null.

Comment: You've added `col` but you aren't actually using it for anything, it can be removed - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/231aa/4. They have everything they need to solve the problem in their data, the problem with their query is they had the `attributeId` and `attributevalue` reversed.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a misplacement of columns in the PIVOT clause. 
Try this:

```
SELECT [Identifier], [1] as [Geography], [2] as [Temperature], [3] as [Humidity], [4] as [Pressure]
FROM
    (
        SELECT [Identifier], [AttributeID], [AttributeValue]
        FROM dbo.StringAttributeValues
    ) as A

PIVOT
(
    max(AttributeValue)
    for AttributeID in ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) as B
```